# ActiveRelation uniquness by column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

SO i have active relation like:

```
[[id:1, post_id: 10, user_id:2][id:2, post_id:11, user_id:2]]
```

When i say `relation.uniq`, it doesn't return one value, because id's of objects are different(which is obvious behavior).

How do i get only unique object, but not by full fields, but only by some specific field, for example `(:user_id)`

I've tried to use distinct, but that returns me only array of fields, instead of active relation or objects

As result, i'd want to get an active relation where, field user_id would be unique

Though i'm not sure if this is good idea, maybe i should use some other methodics to get what i want, because i'm starting to understand, that this is not the best idea

Comment: What do you expect to return, first object, or last, and why? What do you want to return, user_id or user as object or something else?

Comment: ok  
{id: 1, u_id: 2}, {id: 2, u_id: 2}. Well objects are not unique. Which object do you expect? What is the rule of your expectation?

Comment: in this case even .first would work, since it doesnt matters for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you use `distinct`? When I run

```
> Model.select('DISTINCT column')
```

it seems to return an object of class `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pluck](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck).

```
Model.distinct.pluck(:user_id)
```

Examples:

```
Person.pluck(:id)
# SELECT people.id FROM people
# => [1, 2, 3]

Client.distinct.pluck(:role)
# SELECT DISTINCT role FROM clients
# => ['admin', 'member', 'guest']
```

Comment: right, but i will get only array of fields, while i'd want to have active relation, to apply other methods(get child object of record, etc)